# how to Override a hide method in webChromeClient in android

Tags: android, hide

source code in webChromeClient.class in android.

```
 /**
 * Tell the client that the selection has been copied or canceled.
 * @hide
 */
public void onSelectionDone(WebView view) {
}
```

is there any way to override that method in my project?
like

```
WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() 
{
        @Override
        public void onSelectionDone(WebView view)
        {   
        }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get From This

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: this is different.In my case, the method is a hiden method.
"/**
 * Tell the client that the selection has been copied or canceled.
 * @hide
 */"

Comment: link to a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844320/can-i-override-a-hidden-but-public-method-and-call-its-super-method