# Java how to extend a hidden class

Tags: java, android

I need to override a method of a hidden class (marked with @hide) which is only visible within its package. Is there any way to extend it?

More specifically, I need to override `getNextCursorOffset()` of *android.widget.Editor* because that method does not work very well with `ReplacementSpan`.

Comment: why not use decorator of your own with all the methods of Editor and just getNextCursorOffset of yours?

Comment: @SMA You mean cloning Editor.java? That would be crazy since it has 5K+ lines of code.

Comment: Not cloning. You would compose editor in your new class and just delegate the call of other methods to Editor instance while for getNextCursorOffset, you would implement your own logic.

Comment: @SMA, That won't work if getNextCursorOffset() is package protected, it won't be visible to the code in a different package. Would've worked had that method been protected.

Comment: @SMA I see. But that won't be easy too. It's not a direct call and the whole logic is complex. Lots of private members need to be modified which themselves are not accessible either.

Comment: @Egor if OP can create the same package then that would work. Am assuming its protected..

Comment: @Egor @SMA It seems that even I define the same package, `Editor` still can't be resolved. Is there anyway to modify the SDK source? I've googled a lot and didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the same package, `android.widget` within your project. Then you can extend it:

```
public class ProjectSpecificEditor extends Editor {
    // constructors et all
    public int getNextCursorOffset() {
        //...
    }

}
```

But note that this is discouraged. I.e. the next version of the framework might change some of the classes / method signatures. Then you can blame only yourself.

Comment: Sorry I didn't test it. Even I define the same package, Android Studio still can't resolve `Editor`. Is there anything that should be configured?

Comment: A good cross-check is whether you can compile it from command-line.

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea from [ryan gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23476412/11427841)

Basically, anything marked with `@hide` is removed when compiling the framework, which Android Studio uses to compile your code. You can fine that in `\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-xx\android.jar`. What ryan proposed, was to either compile android framework yourself without the `@hide`, or to take an already compiled framework from a rooted phone (because `@hide` doesn't affect code used in actual phones)

An simpler alternative in my opinion is to simply extract the `.class` file from `android.jar`, use any Java bytecode editor, and just add the missing method. Then replace the file in `android.jar`.

However, just as Tamas Rev mentioned, methods marked with `@hide` were never meant to be accessed, therefore there's no guarantee that it existed in older versions, or that the behavior is consistent across versions, or that it will exist in the future!